# How to refresh an alias each time it is executed

Tags: bash, ubuntu, alias

I have this alias to check the temperature of my Raspberry Pi:

```
gpu=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | awk -F "[= \']" '{print $2}')

cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)

cpu=$(echo "$cpu / 100 * 0.1" | bc)

cpuf=$(echo "(1.8 * $cpu) + 32" | bc)

gpuf=$(echo "(1.8 * $gpu) + 32" | bc)

alias temp="echo \"CPU => $cpuf 'F\" && echo \"GPU => $gpuf 'F\""
```

It is running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. It works well, but when I want to check the temp, I have to close the terminal I have open and open a new one. E.g. After I execute `temp` once in a terminal, it stores that data until I close and reopen the terminal. I was hoping there was a way to have the alias refresh each time I execute it. This alias is in /etc/bash.bashrc
Thank you!

Comment: Does it have to be an alias?

Comment: Why not just use a function?

Comment: What you have there, are five assignments and one alias definition. The two first assignments seem to run commands that actually fetch the temperatures, the alias just prints the stored values. So, assuming all that is in your shell's startup file, the temperature values get stored when _the shell starts_, not when you run the alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like it would be better suited as a function.  (Which can/should also be added to your bashrc and simulates a simple command much like an alias):

```
temp () {
    gpu=$(/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp | awk -F "[= \']" '{print $2}')
    cpu=$(</sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
    cpu=$(bc <<<"$cpu / 100 * 0.1")
    cpuf=$(bc <<<"(1.8 * $cpu) + 32")
    gpuf=$(bc <<<"(1.8 * $gpu) + 32")

    echo -e "CPU => $cpuf °F\nGPU => $gpuf °F"
}
```

Comment: Trying to emulate "℉".

Comment: `printf 'CPU => %s F\nGPU => %s F\n' "$cpuf" "$gpuf"`

Comment: You could even turn the C->F conversion into its own function and call that in `temp`, but that may make it too "big" for such a simple task.